# Difference between "Warm regards" and "Best regards"

Tags: differences

Is there any difference between *Warm regards* and *Best regards*?

Comment: *Warm Regards* is relatively unusual, even in the more common form *Warmest Regards*. It's probably best reserved for close friends & relatives. *Best Regards* is quite common, even in "semi-formal" emails and business letters today. Though I personally wouldn't use it *unless I've personally met the addressee*. It's also fine for personal correspondence - but some may feel it's become a bit meaningless/impersonal for that purpose, now that it's so common in business communications.

Comment: Thanks. So, "Warm Regards" for close friends & relatives. "Best Regards" for common people. Put it as answer and I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: Also, it's becoming more and more common for people to simply write "Best," and leave it at that. I rather prefer it for being concise.

Comment: What is appropriate varies from place to place.  Have you ever received a letter from India signed "Your humble and obedient servant" or something?

Comment: @GEdgar Why India?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*Regards* is a synonym for *greetings*. Either phrase would be used in a formal letter; you wouldn't use these greetings in a letter to a close friend or family member. *Warm* sounds a bit warmer than *best*, but basically the two are interchangeable.

"Warmest regards" I use for close friends and relatives.

Comment: +1 Your phrase "Warm sounds a bit warmer than best" is another one that I find it funny. Good phrase.

Comment: No, you would not use *regards* in a formal letter. Formal letters require *Yours sincerely* or *Yours faithfully*. *Regards* is fine for email, since email is less formal than letters.

Comment: +1 because it's a good answer, but also as a peace offering (see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46857/what-does-quick-parts-mean/46861#46861).  Sorry I upvoted without adding an answer myself, but how I could I when you've answered so  completely? :-)

Comment: How about "kind regards" then?

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't use "regards" in any form for close friends or family - it sounds way too formal. However, "regards" on its own in an email is fine for someone I don't know, yet I am having an informal conversation with e.g., admin for the house, kids etc. It sounds friendly, yet not too personal.

Best to use "Yours sincerely" for initial correspondence with business people. "Yours faithfully" is a bit old school.

Comment: I was taught (and still practise): "Yours sincerely" for where you have addressed an individual by name, as in "Dear Mr Jones", at the beginning of the letter; and "Yours faithfully" where you have not addressed the letter to an indivdual, as in "Dear Sirs".

Answer (score 5):

Regards = Neutral; Sincerely = Expressing sincerity; Best Regards = Acquaintances; All the best - Professional; and Very Truly Yours = Corporate America

Comment: “All the best” is _not_ a valediction I’d expect in a professional context, except perhaps in a friendly and personal letter telling me I didn’t get the job/promotion.

Comment: I wouldn't regard "Regards" as neutral when used on its own, but slightly negative. Especially for someone who always signs their emails with "Best regards" or "Kind regards", using "Regards" in contrast, perhaps especially in British English, could be a sign that something is not fully in order. Does anyone else see this or am I just mistaken in my interpretation?

Comment: @dionyziz, I certainly use a dry 'Regards' when my correspondent has exhausted my patience or is about to, but I'm not a native speaker...

Answer (score 2):

Best regards seems very positive.  Much like saying "**Good Luck**" or "**Have a Great Day**".

Warm regards can be taken a few ways.  But if I wrote *Warm Regards* it would mean (to me) "**Thinking about You**".  It sounds very personal.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Oxford English Dictionary regards as a valediction literally means “best wishes,” therefore writing “best regards” is redundant.  Avoid using it altogether.  “Warm regards” and “Kind regards” were both created specifically to avoid this misusage. Both should be used only with close friends or colleagues.

Comment: Does the OED really say "best regards" is redundant? That's how I interpret your first sentence, which is misleading. I'm pretty certain that these terms are capitalized too. Can you backup your claim that *Warm Regards* and *Kind Regards* were created **after** "best wishes"?

Answer (score 0):

To the extent there is no real meaning attached to it, best regards means something like, I wish you well. However, when used as closing ; Warm regards and Best regards don't have much real meaning attached to them and are just polite ways to end a letter. In that way, they are much the same as sincerely.But for the opinion, I would say it's better to use "Best Regards" instead of Warm or warmest.

One more thing, it's a reply to a specific comment here. 
**"A letter from India signed "Your humble and obedient servant" or something"**

Ans- Yes I saw and I know why they use that form of salutation. It's a British form of saying a farewell, a valediction. It's a formal Victorian format that maintained by the British in that era when India was ruled by them and as a consequence Indian people grasp the same form. 
I wouldn't say to abandon a wonderfully rich language but I do however suggest to use an appropriate (i.e contemporary) form that your reader will easily understand because a writing to prospects and customers aim for readability not a literary prize or award for Victorian prose.

Comment: Wouldn’t you worry that this might come off as formulaic and therefore insincere?