# Appropriate response to Best wishes

Tags: letter-writing

I always feel uneasy about letter endings.  I sometimes use (1) Yours
sincerely, (2) Yours faithfully, and (3) Yours &c.  But none of these seem an
appropriate response to a correspondent's Best wishes.  (1) and (2) would be
too formal a response, and in (3) there is, I suppose, some jocularity and
familiarity, which may not always be appropriate.  My unsatisfactory solution
is to drop the valediction entirely when I have received Best wishes.  In a
way, I feel Best wishes is too informal---and also inappropriate because it
assumes I /need/ my correspondent's best wishes, it is almost like saying 'good
luck'---, and that in using it my correspondent has forfeited the right to
receive any valediction in return.  Or have I missed something, is there an
appropriate response to Best wishes, if my sentiments are granted?

To put the question another way, what is the most formal response to Best wishes that will not be awkwardly formal in contrast?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I convey my Best wishes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246910/how-should-i-convey-my-best-wishes)

Comment: Maybe [Difference between “Warm regards” and “Best regards”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46977/) then. If I hadn't cited a "related" earlier question I'd still have closevoted (POB).

Answer (score 1):

I came across this. I hope it helps.

[Business writing blog](http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2006/01/with_best_wishe.html)
"It's the "complimentary close" or "complimentary closing" that business writers are wondering about, those phrases that come before the signature in a letter. The complimentary closes below are listed from (1) very formal to (14) very warm.

1. Very truly yours,
2. Respectfully,
3. Yours truly,
4. Sincerely yours,
5. Sincerely,
6. Best regards,
7. Kind regards,
8. With thanks,
9. Best wishes,
10. Cordially,
11. Warm wishes,
12. Warm regards,
13. Warmly,
14. Affectionately "

Comment: Perhaps you should add **Love** and **XXX** as the two final entries! I admit I've sometimes just written **Yours etc.** in "stroppy" formal contexts. In a letter of complaint to faceless bureaucrats, for example - where I'd *like* whoever's reading it to feel at least *slightly* insulted, but I doubt it's ever worked.

Comment: I once  received a letter from India signed as "Your humble and obedient servant" or something like that